# Why this Bash list expression and variable calling fails?

Tags: bash, array

Code

```
#!/bin/bash
startTimes=$(seq 300 10 330)
for startTime in ${startTimes[@]};
do
        endTime=${startTime}+10
        echo ${endTime} > /tmp/111test # Output literally: startTimes+10 
done
echo "Last endTime: "${endTime}
```

Output with `bash -x ...`

```
++ seq 300 10 330
+ startTimes='300
310
320
330'
+ for startTime in '${startTimes[@]}'
+ endTime=300+10
+ echo 300+10
+ for startTime in '${startTimes[@]}'
+ endTime=310+10
+ echo 310+10
+ for startTime in '${startTimes[@]}'
+ endTime=320+10
+ echo 320+10
+ for startTime in '${startTimes[@]}'
+ endTime=330+10
+ echo 330+10
+ echo 'Last endTime: 330+10'
Last endTime: 330+10
```

Expected output

```
310
320
330
340
```

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 backsports

Comment: Since `seq [OPTION]... FIRST INCREMENT LAST`, I'd put `startTimes=$(seq 300 10 340)`

Comment: @don_crissti You are right about `${var[@]}`! I got it; it is required with `seq` too. - - It still does not compute the summation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don_crissti's answer in comments which points out two mistakes in the declaration of `startTimes` and in use of `${var[@]}` which has to be used with `seq` output

```
startTimes=( $(seq 300 10 330) )

for startTime in "${startTimes[@]}";
do
        endTime=$(( ${startTime}+10 ))
        echo ${endTime} > /tmp/111test 
done

echo "Last endTime: "${endTime}
```